# Unable to install OMNeT++ 5.4 for Windows

Tags: omnet++

When I run command `./configure` I receive below mentioned error:

> configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.

I have installed Qt5.9.0 after receiving above error, installed mingw-32bit but still receiving same error. Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The `OMNeT++` package for Windows contains all libraries and other tools (including JRE), so there is no need to install anything separately.

---

To install `OMNeT++` in Windows one should:

1. Download a proper version of `OMNeT++` - i.e. `OMNeT++ 5.4 (Windows)`.
2. Turn off aniti-virus real time protection.
3. Extract the whole archive into a directory whose name doesn't contain spaces.
4. Double-click `mingwenv.cmd`, then press any key.
5. After some time in the `mingwenv` console type: `./configure`, then `make`.
6. In the `mingwenv` console type `omnetpp` to start `OMNeT++`.

Later, to start `OMNeT++` one should double click `mingwenv.cmd`, type `omnetpp` and do not close console.

Comment: I wish I had seen this 8 hours earlier. I also wish I could point to this from the official document. This is the way to go for Windows...

Answer (score 1):

I have removed polish characters from directory path and it solved thie problem. Check if directory has any special characters in directory path.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share what worked for me. After installing the Qt package, remove the existing omnetpp directory and extract it from the zip file again. Run mingwenv.cmd, so that it initiates the tools extraction and is now able to load the installed Qt package. Running ./configure now doesn't show the error.